# Hide and show a cell of the TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

My tablelayout panel has one column and three rows.  (one docked to Fill panel in each cell.)

Now I would like to be able to hide/show the rows . I want only one row to be visible at any time ( based on a user selection of some radio buttons) and I want to to get resized so it fills all the area of the TableLayoutPanel.

How can I do that? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So why did you use a `TableLayoutPanel`?

Just put three `Panel`s on your form, fill in everyone the content of each row and set the `Dock` property of all three panels to `Fill`. Set two panels `Visible = false` and one to `true`.

If you like to see another panel, just make it visible and hide the other two (based on your radio button settings).

Answer (score 20):

If rows in your TableLayoutPanel is autosized then hiding content panel will hide cell where panel placed too.

Comment: thanks, it could hide the panel but not the Cell.. cell is still there? Am I missing something?

Comment: @BDotA, are you sure that your row is autosized?

Comment: well on in the properties box of TableLayoutPanel there was a "Rows" property, I clicked on it, another dialog opened. my rows were listed there. there was a CellType radio buttons options in there I think. so I clicked on each of my rows and selected AutoSize for it.... this is what I did.

Comment: Same Problem Here: All Contentcontrols `DockingStyle.Fill` every row autosize. When `Control.Visible = false` the row doesnt get resized (to height = 0)

Answer (score 20):

I would suggest setting the other rows heights to 0 is the easiest way:

Row one:

```
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[1].Height = 0;
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this

```
TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles[1].SizeType = SizeType.Absolute;
TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles[1].Width = 0;
```

Answer (score 6):

My scenario is similar. I needed a TableLayoutPanel with 4 rows each of which needed to be visible according to a checkbox selection. So instead of only showing one row at a time, I can show 1 - 4.
After designing the layout with 1 column and 4 rows, the controls were added and Dock set to Fill for each one.
Then in a single CheckedChanged event handler for the checkboxes, I coded as shown below. It's kind of a brute force method, but, Hey...it works!

```
    private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        int seldCount = checkBox1.Checked ? 1 : 0;
        seldCount += checkBox2.Checked ? 1 : 0;
        seldCount += checkBox3.Checked ? 1 : 0;
        seldCount += checkBox4.Checked ? 1 : 0;

        float pcnt = 0;
        if (seldCount == 1)
            pcnt = 1;
        if (seldCount == 2)
            pcnt = 0.5f;
        if (seldCount == 3)
            pcnt = 0.33f;
        if (seldCount == 4)
            pcnt = 0.25f;

        int newHeight = (int)(tableLayoutPanel1.Height * pcnt);

        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[0].SizeType = SizeType.Percent;
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[0].Height = newHeight;
        }
        else
        {
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[0].SizeType = SizeType.Absolute;
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[0].Height = 0;
        }

        if (checkBox2.Checked)
        {
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[1].SizeType = SizeType.Percent;
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[1].Height = newHeight;
        }
        else
        {
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[1].SizeType = SizeType.Absolute;
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[1].Height = 0;
        }

        if (checkBox3.Checked)
        {
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[2].SizeType = SizeType.Percent;
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[2].Height = newHeight;
        }
        else
        {
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[2].SizeType = SizeType.Absolute;
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[2].Height = 0;
        }

        if (checkBox4.Checked)
        {
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[3].SizeType = SizeType.Percent;
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[3].Height = newHeight;
        }
        else
        {
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[3].SizeType = SizeType.Absolute;
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[3].Height = 0;
        }
        this.ResumeLayout();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

To hide row try this!!

```
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[1].SizeType = SizeType.Absolute;
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[1].Height = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

I had similar task to do and my solution is following:

Add a TableLayoutPanel to your form (or any container).

Set TableLayoutPanel's columns and rows count to 1 and size to 100%.

Set Dock to Fill.

Set GrowStyle to fixedSize.

Set AutoSize to true.

Then programmatically add all of three forms/controls, one of which you have to show depending on radio button choice. Be sure that only one of them is visible. That could be done with initial FirstControl.Show(); and then on each RadioButton event hide the current one and show another. you may "remember" in local variable (say: "currentlyVisibleControl"  the reference which is currently visible)

note: if you will .Show() more than one at time. then TableLayoutPanel wil fire the exception that it is full and can't add any more item.

P.S. In My own example I have TableLayoutPanel in MDI window and three forms which substitute each other on button clicks on them so I think copying my source code will complicate the "verbal" example.

P.P.S. From my experience Visual Studio does some weird things in design mode sometimes. I had to remove and re-add the TableLayoutPanel to set properties correctly and get the results both in designer and in runtime. So if either autosize or absolute/percent values are not depicted on designer screen it may be designers problem rather that yours. JUST DELETE IT AND RETRY.

Answer (score 0):

I tried fooling around with the `Height` and `SizeType` properties, but it was giving me odd results. For example, the Labels on the target row were being hidden, but the TextBoxes were not.

Here is an extension class that I came up with using @arbiter's suggestion of hiding the children Controls of the row.

```
// these methods only works on rows that are set to AutoSize
public static class TableLayoutPanelExtensions
{

    public static void HideRows(this TableLayoutPanel panel, params int[] rowNumbers)
    {
        foreach (Control c in panel.Controls)
        {
            if (rowNumbers.Contains(panel.GetRow(c)))
                c.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    public static void ShowRows(this TableLayoutPanel panel, params int[] rowNumbers)
    {
        foreach (Control c in panel.Controls)
        {
            if (rowNumbers.Contains(panel.GetRow(c)))
                c.Visible = true;
        }

    }

}
```