# Hide a row in TableLayout

Tags: c#, .net, tablelayoutpanel

I have a table layout that contains three rows and one column:

[image]

What I want is to hide the second row before the progress completes, like this:

[image]

On the internet, I found two things:

1. Delete the row - **I don't want to delete the row**, just temporarily hide it!
2. Set row height to 0 - didn't work, for some reason part of the inner data was still visible.

So how do I really HIDE the row. Not remove, not resize but actually hide it from view.

Comment: What tool did you use to do your UX mock-up?  I like it!

Comment: Did you try this? tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[1].SizeType = SizeType.Absolute;
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[1].Height = 0;   ................OR....... tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[1] = new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 0F);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide and show a cell of the TableLayoutPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290414/hide-and-show-a-cell-of-the-tablelayoutpanel)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hiding and showing rows in a `TableLayoutPanel` is not really straightforward.

Based on your UI mock, I assume first and third rows are set to `Absolute` while second one is `AutoSize` or `Percent`. I am also assuming that `Dock` for panel is set to `Fill`. Now, here is what I would do in this scenario.

Add an empty row in the end with `SizeType` set to `AutoSize`. When the user action begins (say a button click) do the following:

```
// RowStyles index is index of the row you are dealing with
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[1].SizeType = SizeType.Absolute;
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[1].Height = 0;
```

Since there is an auto-sized row in the end, all the other rows would move up and your form will have empty space at the bottom. This will retain your desired layout. When the action is completed, you can set the row in question back to `Percent` or `AutoSize`.

Comment: Your assumptions were correct - when I explicitly set the size to Absolute, it worked.

Answer (score 4):

If the table layout row size style is autosize the show/hide behaviour can be achieved by setting the visible property of row content (e.g., groupbox) to be true or false.

Answer (score 1):

As Jie Zhao said.

If all your rows styles have the `SizeType` property set to `Absolute`, but the row style you want to hide is set to `AutoSize`, all you need to do is set the property `Visible` to `False` in every control inside the row style.

In my example, my TableLayoutPanel has three columns.

[See example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRDqD.jpg)

```
label1.Visible = false;
label2.Visible = false;
label3.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow danish suggestion is not working fine. There are still visible controls, depending on style- check box "clasic" disappears, meanwhile "box" style is a bit visible. TextBox is visible in "hidden" row and if you remove two rows, only then one Textbox is hidden.

And yes, there is extra autosize row and column with empty cells:

[image]

So, the only proper way is to hide the children:

```
For i = 0 To My_Table_layout_panel.Controls.Count - 1
                    If My_Table_layout_panel.GetRow(My_Table_layout_panel.Controls(i)) = LAST_RAM_ROW Then
                        My_Table_layout_panel.Controls(i).Hide()
                    End If
                Next
```

or show them:

```
For i = 0 To My_Table_layout_panel.Controls.Count - 1
                    If My_Table_layout_panel.GetRow(My_Table_layout_panel.Controls(i)) = LAST_RAM_ROW Then
                        My_Table_layout_panel.Controls(i).Show()
                    End If
                Next
```

Now it works like a charm. `LAST_RAM_ROW` is just the row to hide.